# New software engineer not invited to user experience meeting. Should I be worried?

Tags: software-industry, performance, software

Background: I'm a fairly green software engineer that just graduated from college. I got hired by the company I interned at for over 2 years during college and have been with the company for almost 3 years total now.
We are a team of 1 manager and 3 software engineers.

Recently we had a UI/UX meeting in which some higher ups from the company and the engineers (besides me) met to discuss what we like and dislike about the current user experience of our product. The manager and the 2 senior engineers were invited to this meeting but I was not. My manager stated that the reasoning was because he didn't want to have too many people present and thus increase the amount of debate potential within the meeting. However, I can't help but wonder if there is some other reason why I was not invited to this meeting. I would think that being a developer for this application, I should at least be able to hear and understand how users are experiencing our product since that is pretty valuable knowledge. I am not an opinionated or argumentative person so I don't think that was the reason I wasn't invited.

Am I overthinking this, or am I not picking up on something that I should be worried about?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You’re over thinking it. Don’t worry about it. After the meeting, you’ll probably be given tasks by the seniors and hopefully some information on what was discussed.

Sometimes it’s better for the meeting to have as few people as possible to meet the meeting requirements, otherwise things tend to overrun and over-complicate.

After a while, you’ll be thankful for not being pulled into long, drawn out meetings all the time and allowed to get on with your work in peace...

Comment: @LaneL enjoy the time you have now to not be in meetings, too, as it won't be long until you long for the days you didn't have to be in meetings ;-)

Comment: @enderland Good point!